# Just a "Congratulations" to an active community

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to say that I enjoy how this SE is brimming with activity both on the main site and meta. I love how much voting is going on, yet hope that reviews, flagging and edits are similarly frequent.

Congratulations on what looks like a successful launch. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 9):

We appreciate your support. Edits seem very common but I have not noticed much flagging yet. That might be something we should work on.

Answer (score 3):

thanks a lot, I really start to enjoy this place! My guess is that a lot of active users are new to SE like me and that it takes a while to get used how much stuff you're allowed to do as a normal user on here. If someone is used to classic fora like btct than the concept of editing other people's stuff is weird somehow.